# public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener 1), how come reference name is a digit "1"?

Tags: android

Hey im currently studying android programming on my own. and i have this question that i cant really find on the internet. Code below is the public method of class View the setOnClickListener:

public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener 1){
.......
}

what i dont understand on this particular method is its parameter, i know that this need a reference to that interface so that we can call a anonymous object or pass a class that implement this OnClickListener interface. On the parameter the Reference name to the interface is "1" which is a number, and base on what i understand is you cannot name a reference to a digit?.How can that reference name is a digit? i tried to recreate a method like this but only got errors. Thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: It's the letter "l" (L), not the digit 1 (one). It would be better to name the parameter "listener" to prevent this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, a variable name must begin with a letter (a-z, A-Z) or underscore (_) or dollar symbol ($). It cannot begin with a digit (0-9), because it might be confuse with a number.

**Problem:** In your case, it seems you have a typo here, it's lowercase '**l**' (**l**ove, **l**ike, **l**eave, etc..) instead digit **1**.

**Solution:** You should change lowercase '**l**' to **listener** string to resolve the error and avoid confusing.

```
/**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not
 * clickable, it becomes clickable.
 *
 * @param listener The callback that will run
 *                 
 * @see #setClickable(boolean)
 */
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable View.OnClickListener listener) {
    if (isClickable()) {
        setClickable(true);
    }
    getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = listener;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid Java syntax. Variable name cannot be digit only. See "Naming" section in docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Comment: that's what i know aswell that it cannot be digit only, thats why im confuse to this. and that code is from android studio

Comment: AS is not creating this code using AI but rather plain template or snippet. So you apparently has broken template in your AS or so. No magic here. Check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-and-code-templates.html and investigate around that.